# ServiceStack ORMLite: Mutliple Column GroupBy With Table Aliases

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I wish to use ORMLite to group by multiple aliased tables but I seem to have hit an issue.

When using Sql.TableAlias with an anonymous type in the GroupBy of an SqlExpression the SQL generated for the group by contains the property name from the anonymous type (i.e. AliasName."Column" As PropertyName).

The code below can reproduce this issue:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}

public class Stuff
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? ThingId { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set;  }
}

string brokenGroupBy = db
    .From<Thing>()
    .Join<Stuff>((thing, stuff) => stuff.ThingId == thing.Id && stuff.Type == 1, db.TableAlias("StuffTypeOne"))
    .Join<Stuff>((thing, stuff) => stuff.ThingId == thing.Id && stuff.Type == 2, db.TableAlias("StuffTypeTwo"))
    .GroupBy<Thing, Stuff>((thing, stuff) => new
    {
        ThingId = thing.Id,
        StuffTypeOneId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeOne"),
        StuffTypeTwoId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeTwo")
    })
    .Select<Thing, Stuff>((thing, stuff) => new
    {
        ThingId = thing.Id,
        StuffTypeOneId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeOne"),
        StuffTypeTwoId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeTwo")
    })
    .ToMergedParamsSelectStatement();
```

The SQL generated and stored in the brokenGroupBy string is the following:

```
SELECT "thing"."id"      AS "ThingId", 
       StuffTypeOne."id" AS StuffTypeOneId, 
       StuffTypeTwo."id" AS StuffTypeTwoId 
FROM   "thing" 
       INNER JOIN "stuff" "StuffTypeOne" 
               ON ( ( "StuffTypeOne"."thingid" = "thing"."id" ) 
                    AND ( "StuffTypeOne"."type" = 1 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN "stuff" "StuffTypeTwo" 
               ON ( ( "StuffTypeTwo"."thingid" = "thing"."id" ) 
                    AND ( "StuffTypeTwo"."type" = 2 ) ) 
GROUP  BY "thing"."id", 
          StuffTypeOne."id" AS stufftypeoneid, 
          StuffTypeTwo."id" AS stufftypetwoid
```

Are table aliases not supported in this case or is there a different way to specify the group by in this scenario?

I have achieved my desired result using a custom SQL expression in the group by but would prefer a solution that did not require SQL strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've published an update to OrmLite available from v5.8.1, now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) that will also strip the aliases from Group By Expressions so your group by expression:

```
.GroupBy<Thing, Stuff>((thing, stuff) => new
{
    ThingId = thing.Id,
    StuffTypeOneId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeOne"),
    StuffTypeTwoId = Sql.TableAlias(stuff.Id, "StuffTypeTwo")
})
```

Should now generate something like:

```
thing.Id, "StuffTypeOne"."Id", "StuffTypeTwo"."Id"
```

Although since you've already defined the aliases in your SELECT expression you can reuse those instead:

```
.GroupBy<Thing, Stuff>((thing, stuff) => new
{
    ThingId = thing.Id,
    StuffTypeOneId = "StuffTypeOneId",
    StuffTypeTwoId = "StuffTypeTwoId"
})
```

Or you can use an object array for a terser expression:

```
.GroupBy<Thing, Stuff>((thing, stuff) => new object[]
{
    thing.Id,
    "StuffTypeOneId",
    "StuffTypeTwoId"
})
```